# Priorvalue in Validation rule

Tags: validation

Iam trying to simplify my validation rule but i get error. My VR restricts users from role from chaning ownerid for subset of users, since all my users first name is "TBD" i want to simpify the rule by adding owner.firstname, here is my rule

```
AND(
     OR($UserRole.Id  = "00E30000000vEST",
        $UserRole.Id  = "00E40000001CZB5"),
        ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
        PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> "00540000000zpgS",
        PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> "00540000000oWNX",
        PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> "00540000000lkIN",
        PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> "00540000001SyUq",
        PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> "00540000001UnYg",
        PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> "00540000002FltR",
        PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> "00540000002nKbr",
        PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> "00540000002JAiR",
        PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> "00540000002IeDq",
        PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> "00540000002nU49",
        PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> "00540000002nU4Y",
        PRIORVALUE(OwnerId) <> "00540000002nU4T"
)
```

I want to use `PRIORVALUE(Owner.FirstName <> "TBD")` but i get this error:

> Incorrect argument type for function 'PRIORVALUE()'.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't reference the field directly, so you have to use a formula:

```
Field Name: Owner_First_Name__c
Return Type: Text
Formula: Owner.FirstName
```

Then, you can reference it as such:

```
PRIORVALUE(Owner_First_Name__c) = 'TBD'
```

Comment: I even created formula field and tried even text field but looks like i can't use these fields in Priorvalue function, any other ideas ?

Comment: you can try BEGINS(PRIORVALUE(OwnerName)),"TBD") and see if it works..

Comment: There is no field called OwnerName.

Comment: @Admin_BA I've tested this in my developer org, and it works. If you're having trouble, try using the "Insert Field" button and see if that helps. Maybe you should update your question with your latest attempt using the formula field so we can have another try at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try: PRIORVALUE(Owner.FirstName) <> "TBD"

PRIORVALUE takes a field and results in what the fields prior value was, which should then be compared to your value.

Edit: It does not appear you can use priorvalue function with that field

> Error: The PRIORVALUE function cannot reference the Owner.FirstName field.

Comment: Still same error :(